# Swift - how to convert an array of objects stored locally (filemanager) to a newer one? (with added attributes)

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

So I've been researching into this and still resulting in nothing.
Basically, I've got an array of objects that I stored to filemanager. The object, say User, has 2 attributes.

```
class User {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}
```

Upon new updates, I added new attribute.

```
class User {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int
}
```

Filemanager still able to identifies the file and read it. But since they are different now, I can't perform a check on my view controller. For example, I want to check if this new User exist inside the stored arrays. It will return false since they are different.
Any help?

edit:
my class do have and id

```
class User: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    var id: { firstName }
   // rest of attributes
}
```

edit 2:
here's my storing and loading the data class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct DataPersistEngine {

    var users: [User] = []


    struct SavedData: Codable {
        let users: [User]

    }

    private let filePath: URL
    private let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    private let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    init() {
        do {
            filePath = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                   in: .userDomainMask,
                                                   appropriateFor: nil,
                                                   create: false).appendingPathComponent("SavedDatas")
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: filePath) {
                decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .base64
                let savedData = try decoder.decode(SavedData.self, from: data)
                self.users = savedData.users
            }
        } catch let error {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    mutating func saveUser(user: User) {
        if users.contains(user) {
            users.removeAll(where: { $0 == user })
        } else {
            users.append(user)
        }
        save()
    }


    private func save() {
        do {
            let savedData = SavedData(users: users)
            let data = try encoder.encode(savedData)
            try data.write(to: filePath, options: .atomicWrite)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error while saving datas: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        encoder.dataEncodingStrategy = .base64
    }

}
```

Comment: So you are storing your classed to disk? Show the code for storing and loading your `User` objects.

Comment: Added the edits. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Also, do you have backward compatibility requirements? E.g. if you app is in the AppStore, and the `User` class doesn't have an `age` attribute,  and now you wish to add this attribute and make the app work correctly for old users?
Or is this just a pet project? :)

Comment: I do want to publish it to the app store. As I am not on my computer right now, I can't do much help trying to 'fix' the bug. But what Joakim suggested seems promising and I could see that work logically. So no matter if I added the content, as long as the id is equal, it will still be true.

Comment: So if this app isn't published yet, it's enough just to delete an app from your iPhone, then install again with Xcode, and then only new version of User class will be stored/loaded.

Comment: Ah but I already did publish it for beta (i've got some testers already)  and removing the user's data won't be a good move hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your own definition of what makes two objects equal

```
extension User {
    static func == (lhs: User , rhs: User) -> Bool {
        return lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName && lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName
    } 
}
```

Comment: So on my tableviewVC, instead of doing: self.users.contains(user), I do this instead?

Comment: Ah so this will be called when I called the saveUser function on my DataPersistEngine class? (see edit)

Comment: Hi there, just tested with the suggested codeblocks and it went smoothly! Thanks